# jQuery mousewheel issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I have a function that prevents the default behavior of mouse wheel and it makes it scroll horizontally, but the problem is that when the window width is smaller than 970px the default behave doesn't work even though i use `return true;`

Code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 970) {
        $('.swiper-container').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * event.deltaFactor);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    } else {
        $('.swiper-container').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollTop -= (delta * event.deltaFactor);
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `bind` adds an event listener, and not replace it. So you are adding several listeners each time you resize. Instead, you could just check the width inside it.

```
$('.swiper-container').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if($(window).width() >= 970) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * event.deltaFactor);
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        this.scrollTop -= (delta * event.deltaFactor);
    }
});
```

Also, [use `on` instead of `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You also don't need the `else` part if what you want is the default behaviour.